# Spring caching: Update cache conditionally - Return cache value otherwise

Tags: spring, caching, spring-data

Imagine the simple method

```
 public Data getData(int id);
```

There is a `@Scheduled` task that invokes `getData()` periodically. I want the task to never be served by the cache but always put the returned data in the cache. Then there are a bunch of other consumers of `getData()`. I always want them to be served by the cache, unless it happens to not hold the requested data.

How can I do this with Spring?

Answer (score 0):

Well, a simple solution might be to have wrapper methods for your `getData(int id)` method that will allow you to have one *version* that will always be called from cache and another that will update it.

```
@CachePut(value="data")
getDataWithoutCache(int id) {
  return getData(id);
}

@Cachable(value="data")
getDataWithCache(int id) {
  return getData(id)
}
```